# jQuery ajax calls

Tags: jquery

Is there anyway to get access to the settings in the success callback?

```
    $('.chartsRefresher').change(
        function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "/CampaignReportPostHandler.jsp",
                data:({
                    queryPage:$("ul.tabs li.active a").attr("href")
                }),
                success:function(d)
                {
                    alert(settings);
                    var dataTest = d.substring(d.indexOf('('));
                    eval(chartRenderer+"(eval(dataTest))");
                }
            });
            return true;
        }
        );
```

I want to be able to get what the queryPage was when the ajax call was made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your data first:

```
$('.chartsRefresher').change(
        function(){
            var data = {
               queryPage:$("ul.tabs li.active a").attr("href")
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: "/CampaignReportPostHandler.jsp",
                data: data,
                success:function(d)
                {
                    alert(data.queryPage);
                    var dataTest = d.substring(d.indexOf('('));
                    eval(chartRenderer+"(eval(dataTest))");
                }
            });
            return true;
        }
        );
```

And as mentioned, avoid eval if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Declare them with `var`:

```
$('.chartsRefresher').change(function() {
    var ajaxOpts= {
        url: "/CampaignReportPostHandler.jsp",
        data: { /* remove the parentheses around this object */
            queryPage: $("ul.tabs li.active a").attr("href")
        },
        success: function(d) {
            var queryPage = ajaxOpts.data.queryPage;
            var dataTest = d.substring(d.indexOf('('));
            eval(chartRenderer + "(eval(dataTest))");
        }
    };

    $.ajax(ajaxOpts);
    return true;
});
```

---

Side question: *why* are you using eval?

Comment: I am sending json data from the server that will be used by fusioncharts and the only way for it to work was to eval it on return I will get rid of the outer eval once I implement the change suggested.

Comment: @arinte: there is **absolutely no reason to use eval like this.** jQuery will parse JSON for you automatically. If it's not - for instance, because the mime-type of the response is not `application/json` - then you can simply specify one more ajax option: `dataType: 'json'`. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax, or just use [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

Comment: Yes, I agree, but this stupid development environment I am currently living in appends some data at the top of all requests.  That is why you see the d.substr call

Comment: @arinte: in that case, you can still use [`$.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/). Are you sure you're not dealing with JSONP?